# The method usingChromeDriverExecutable(File) is undefined for the type ChromeDriverService in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code is as below:

```
  ChromeDriverService service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
 .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File("E:\\Software\\chromedriver.exe"))
 .usingAnyFreePort().build();
```

It gave the following error:

```
 The method usingChromeDriverExecutable(File) is undefined for the type
 ChromeDriverService
```

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
usingChromeDriverExecutable
```

to

```
usingDriverExecutable
```

Comment: I didn't use that method in my code. I used the following simple code & working well.

File file = new File("F:\\Software Download_Ripon\\WebDriver\\chromedriver_win_22_0_1203_0b\\chromedriver.exe");//v22
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Instead of giving the driver executable path, we can specify the PATH environment variable pointing to the location of the driver executable directory